# Make RxJava Subject or variants behave like AAC LiveData

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Is there a way to make any of RxJava's Subject subclasses behave like a LiveData? I have searched around for this but couldn't find a definite answer.

I have seen some samples where a PublishSubject is being used to relay data or commands from a ViewModel to an activity. But the problem with this is a VM can survive configuration changes, and when the subscription to the VM's PublishSubject is handled by the ususal approach of adding to a CompositeDisposable and clearing it in onDestroy, subsequent commands/data from the VM to the activity will not be received when it restarts from the change. This is unlike a LiveData.

Comment: PublishSubject why? You could use BehaviorRelay???

Comment: Does the second part of the question not apply to a BehaviorRelay? If there's a configuration change survived by the VM, would the activity still be able to receive updates when it is restarted (with the BR subscription cleared in onDestroy prior to the change)

Comment: BehaviorSubject and BehaviorRelay are what you are looking for. When the activities restart it should subscribe again to the same BS and BR. BS and BR emit an item upon subscription.